# How do I stop my array from printing address?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a header, cpp and main class.

```
//Arr.h
class Arr
{
public:
    void setArr();
    void printArr();
private:
    int x[5];
};

//Arr.cpp    
#include "Arr.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void Arr::setArr()
{   
    int x[5] = { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11 };
}

void Arr::printArr()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << x[i] << "\n";
    }
}

//main.cpp
int main()
{
Arr a;
a.setArr();
a.printArr();
}
```

However, when I run the code, a.printArr() prints out array address and not the values contained in the array. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: This line `int x[5] = { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11 };` is a declaration. It declares a new local variable, `x`, which shadows the member variable `Arr::x`.

Comment: So you happened to get array address as indeterminate values? How lucky you are!

Comment: It doesn't print out array address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will print not address but some indeterminate value generated via default-initializing. Initialize the member array instead of the local array to throw away.

```
void Arr::setArr()
{
    x[0] = 2;
    x[1] = 3;
    x[2] = 5;
    x[3] = 7;
    x[4] = 11;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. However is there a shorter way of doing this instead of initializing each element separately? I'm not used to c++ yet so it's very confusing compared to Java.

Comment: Using loop like `static int v[5]={2, 3, 5, 7, 11}; for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) x[i] = v[i];`?

Comment: @Aesis, or a more STLish way... `auto arr = { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11 };
    std::copy(arr.begin(), arr.end(), x);`

Comment: @Aesis, You could use `std::array`. It has some other nice features over raw arrays as well. `std::array<int, 5> x; ... x = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11};`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
void Arr::setArr()
{   
    int x[5] = { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11 };
}
```

the declaration `int x[5]` defines a new array of 5 elements which will be destroyed on exiting that function; and the name `x` hides the data member `Arr::x`.

One way you can do it is this:

```
void Arr::setArr()
{   
    /*static*/ auto arr = { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11 };
    std::copy(arr.begin(), arr.end(), x);
}
```

Full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

class Arr
{
public:
    void setArr();
    void printArr();
private:
    int x[5];
};

using namespace std;

void Arr::setArr()
{   
    /*static*/ auto arr = { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11 };
    std::copy(arr.begin(), arr.end(), x);
}

void Arr::printArr()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << x[i] << "\n";
    }
}

//main.cpp
int main()
{
Arr a;
a.setArr();
a.printArr();
}
```

Comment: note: `auto arr` deduces `arr` as `std::initializer_list<int>`, not an array. (But the code still works)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not printing array address.  Maybe you saw some unexpected numbers and assumed it was an address, but in fact it is [undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/1505939) caused by outputting uninitialized variables.

Your code `int x[5] = ....` failed because this declares a new local variable `x`, it doesn't modify the class member `x`.

Perhaps you tried:

```
x = { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11 };
```

and got compilation errors. This is because C-style arrays may not be assigned. This annoying rule is a hangover from C++'s past. To avoid this problem and many others, you can try to avoid using C-style arrays.    In this case use a C++ array:

```
private:
    std::array<int, 5> x;
```

Then the suggested assignment will work.

Answer (score 0):

As WhiZTiM has already pointed out, your problem is at the setArr function in your class. The reason for this is because in C++ you cannot assign values to the array in the "normal fashion" i.e. using `x = {blah, blah, blah};` (unless you use `std::array<int, ARRAYSIZE>`). In setArr you are creating another array named `x` and then this array is deleted once it is out of scope, and in `printArr` you are printing an array with no values in it yet.

Each value in the array must be set individually in C styled arrays (as shown in MikeCAT's answer).

One solution to this is to create a temporary array with the values you want and assigning the values to your class array through a for loop, i.e.:

```
void Arr::setArr() {
    const int ARRAYSIZE = 5;
    int tmp[ARRAYSIZE] = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11};
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE; ++i) {
        x[i] = tmp[i];
    }
}
```

As M.M also pointed out, can simply change `int x[5]` in your private variables in Arr to `std::array<int, 5> x` and then in setArr simply have the statement: `x = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11};` which is the better option in my opinion and easier to read, but it's also good to know how to use C arrays